# Use an Excel Range as a map for what to return from DB

Tags: vba, excel, adodb, recordset

My client's given me an interesting task that I'm trying to figure out the nicest way to solve and would love to hear your feedback...

Suppose I have data in a DB that I'm querying into Excel VBA (currently stored as an ADODB recordset) that looks as follows:

```
Name:    Char1:    Char2:    Char3:
a        a1        a2        a3
b        b1        b2        b3
c        c1        c2        c3
 .....
```

And then they have the following data contained in the spreadsheet:

```
Name:     NewName:     Char1:    Char2:    Char3:
a         New_a        Yes       NULL      Yes
b         New_b        Yes       Yes       NULL
c         New_c        NULL      NULL      Yes
 .....
```

And they're looking for the output to be as follows:

```
NewName:     Char1:     Char2:     Char3:
New_a        a1         <blank>    a3
New_b        b1         b2         <blank>
New_c        <blank>    <blank>    c3
 .....
```

Basically, **the name needs to be transformed to the new name and wherever there is a `NULL`, that characteristic needs to be excluded** (I hope this makes sense).

Now, I figured out a way to do this using double `Vlookup()` functions, but it's ugly and requires writing the intermediate recordset from the DB into the spreadsheet.

I'm actually curious to see if there's any nice way anyone can think of of accomplishing this... My 3 thoughts are:

1. A query where I join the DB and the Excel sheet based upon `Name` (but I'm not so strong with ADO in VBA, so any help would be really appreciated)
2. Creating 2 `Scripting.Dictionary`s with `Name` as key and linking them that way (but that even seems somewhat inefficient).
3. I don't think this is possible without looping through the recordsets (in which case I'd just create a dictionary as in idea 2), but maybe re-query the 2 recordsets and join them?

Any thoughts / help??

Thanks!!

Comment: will there always be a distinct 1-to-1 relationship between the DB's Name column and the spreadsheet's NewName column?  will the spreadsheet always have the exact same number of rows as the database output?

Comment: Just so I'm clear on what they want.  They want to select what values to return from the DB based on the spreadsheet (the second code group).  If you can make it work with a join (SQL is not my best) then I would do that.  Dictionaries are surprisingly efficient (especially when compared to vLookup).

Comment: I'd use a single dictionary with "Name" as the keys and an array of [newName, Char1Yes_Null, Char2Yes_Null, Char3Yes_Null] as the values.  What do you need to do with the mapped output?

Comment: The output is Excel, correct?  So who cares what is actually returned from the database -- what matters is what's on the spreadsheet.  Why not return the whole recordset (via DataConnection, or VBA, however...) then have a 3rd sheet with formulas like =IF(Sheet2!C4="NULL","",Sheet1!C4) ?  You said the map will always be 1-to-1 with the data set, so this should be super easy.

Comment: @TimWilliams, I think that's the way I'm leaning too. I was thinking of defining a structure of Char1Yes_Null, Char2Yes_Null, etc... Just seems like so much work - You'd have to 1) Bring the range into VB as an array, 2) convert to dictionary, 3) loop through other recordset and use dictionary to populate a new output array... Just seems like there should be an easier way, no?

Comment: @ExactaBox, I might end up doing that, just dislike the idea of having to output the data to a spreadsheet first, but maybe that would prove to be the easiest idea after all....

Comment: @JohnBustos you already have a spreadsheet with the map, so it's not like you have this ultra-clean result output with none of the underlying data/formulas.  But if you do want that, just do a copy > pastespecial > values to a new workbook.  Or code that part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to answer this question, the way I ended up doing this was:

1) I created a separate class `UserTableColumns` which was simply the following:

```
Public NewName as String
Public Char1_YN As Boolean
Public Char2_YN As Boolean
Public Char3_YN As Boolean
```

2) I queried the User-Table range into a recordset (could just as easily done an array, though) and created a dictionary which I populated with:

**KEY =** Name

**Value =** a `UserTableColumns` object defining that row of the user table.

3) I looped through my DB recordset, matched it with the corresponding dictionary entry using the `Name` field, then updated its fields to either be the original value or `Null` and added in the `NewName` field

4) Outputted the recordset using the `CopyFromRecordset()` method.

I'm sure there are more elegant ways and I did manage to get it going with `VLookUp()`, but this seemed the most efficient and easy to maintain for the future.